# Comparing matrix row with string

Tags: python, string, matrix, compare, row

How do you compare a matrix row (ie list of lists) with a given string?

```
index = 99999
for i in range(len(text)):
    if (matrix[i][0:len(text)] == text):
        index = i
```

I want "index" to be the number of row for which "row == text", but the above code outputs 99999.

I know for sure that exactly one of the rows contains the string.
For example, the matrix is

```
 ['a', 'i', 'n', 'e', 'm']
 ['e', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'n']
 ['i', 'n', 'e', 'm', 'a']
 ['m', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'e']
 ['n', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'i']
```

and I want to know which row is "maine" (number 3 in this case).
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe nothing compares true with the string?

Comment: What does the matrix look like? Can you paste the output of `print matrix`?

Comment: @nneonneo, i've posted an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
try:
    index = matrix.index(list(text))
except IndexError:
    index = 99999
```

`list(text)` turns the string into a list of characters. `list.index` searches for the item you specify (using `==` as the equality comparison) and returns its index if found, or raises `IndexError` if not found.

I'd also not recommend using `99999` as the 'not found' value; it's rather safer to use a value like -1 or (better yet) just leave the exception alone unless you intend to handle it.

If you know the string must be in the matrix, then `index = matrix.index(list(text))` is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
for idx,row in enumerate(matrix):
  if ''.join(row) == text:
    print idx
```

Or, as a one-liner:

`idx = [''.join(x) for x in matrix].index(text)`

As for why your attempt didn't work, the reason is this test:

`matrix[i][0:len(text)] == text`

At the point in which you are expecting it to succeed, you are actually comparing a list with a string, but `['m', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'e'] != 'maine'`.   However, `matrix[i][0:len(text)] == list(text)` should have worked.